# Unable to access array index, Array length returns 0, Despite console showing full array

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, get

I am trying to simply add some objects from this callback function to a global array for use later. I am running into an issue with the asynchronous nature of the code and I don't understand why it isn't working.

For both arrays **dl** and **arr**, I cannot access their indices and the console claims their length is 0. However, in chrome dev-tools I can view a dropdown of about 1000 objects in the array, as should be the case.

**dl[0]** or **arr[0]** returns **undefined**, for example.

I should mention this is all within a *componentDidMount()* in my React app. The reason I am making arrays, as opposed to just setting state is that the function is embedded and within a get method here and the indices need to be accesed later anyhow.

```
let dl =[];
let arr=[];

_globalobject.get(
    "/SOME/URL.PARAMETERS/HERE",
    function(response) {
        // authenticated user
        _globalobject.user = response;
        for (let i=0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
            dl.push(response.results[i])
            arr.push(i)
        }
    }
)
console.log(dl, typeof(dl), dl.length) // [] > , 'object', 0
console.log("regular array", arr[0]) // regular array, undefined
```

Comment: You're logging before the request returns

Comment: You've got an **asynchronous** API, so the array isn't populated until the response is received. The `.get()` call itself returns almost immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The global arrays `arr` and `dl` will only be populated with data after the callback that you're passing to `_globalobject.get()` is called.

Currently, logging to console via `console.log()` occurs immediately (ie, before the callback is executed), which is why the arrays are reported empty via the console.

Try moving the `console.log` calls to the end of your callback function so that logging occurs when the arrays are populated with data, like so:

```
let dl =[];
let arr=[];

_globalobject.get(
    "/SOME/URL.PARAMETERS/HERE",
    function(response) {
        // authenticated user
        _globalobject.user = response;
        for (let i=0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
            dl.push(response.results[i])
            arr.push(i)
        }

        // Log to console, when the callback is executed. There
        // should now be data in these arrays, which will cause
        // the console to log expected output
        console.log(dl, typeof(dl), dl.length) // [] > , 'object', 0
        console.log("regular array", arr[0]) // regular array, undefined
    }
)
```

Comment: Good. I suspected something like this. Well. That makes things difficult because I still have to find a way to bind this embedded function....

Comment: You're welcome - is there anything else I can help with? How do you need to bind the function?